# MySQLI prepared failing return results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried thousand of examples but non working, I try to get results on specific row where id= .

My code :

```
 if ($stmt = $func->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM monthlypaymentsrequestlist WHERE id = ?")) { 
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $user['userid']); 
      // Execute the prepared query.
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();

     if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($rows = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo $row['id'];
            }


      }


 }
```

The error i get :

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in
```

How i do it properly ?

Comment: Which tutorial you are learning from?

Comment: Read your error again.

Comment: php.net, also there is tousand of other tuts and examples , i dont know how to make it work properly.

Comment: **which particular tutorial you have got this example from?**

Comment: from no where, this is my own try.

Comment: **This** is what you are doing wrong. Before trying of your own you have to learn first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch_assoc()` is a function of a `mysqli_result`, not the `$stmt` Resource you're trying to use. You need to assign it to the return of `execute()`:

```
if($stmt = $func->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM monthlypaymentsrequestlist WHERE id = ?")) 
{ 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user['userid']); 
    // Execute the prepared query.
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo $row['id'];
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Now i get this : Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: Are you sure your query executes and returns results?

Comment: I am sure its all working. If i do the same with mysql it will work fine, but i want to use mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

fetch_assoc is a method of the mysqli_result class, not the mysqli_stmt class.